# PHP, sort, sort_flags

Tags: php, sorting, flags

I am studying `sort_flags` at this [page](http://php.net/manual/en/function.sort.php) on PHP Manual.

And I don't understand what difference each of these flags represents.

There are only 6 flags, can someone please help me to understand the difference between them. Maybe with some examples. I would be very thankful.

Comment: Blanktext, don't forget to tick (ideally) or +1 answers you find useful.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Array used for testing:

```
$toSort = array(2, 1, "img1", "img2", "img10", 1.5, "3.14", "2.72");
```

Note that `3.14 & 2.72` are strings.

Using `SORT_REGULAR` flag (compare items normally):

```
Array
(
    [0] => 2.72
    [1] => 3.14
    [2] => img1
    [3] => img10
    [4] => img2
    [5] => 1
    [6] => 1.5
    [7] => 2
)
```

Using `SORT_NUMERIC` flag (compare items numerically, so `3.14` is sorted as number not a string):

```
Array
(
    [0] => img10
    [1] => img1
    [2] => img2
    [3] => 1
    [4] => 1.5
    [5] => 2
    [6] => 2.72
    [7] => 3.14
)
```

Using `SORT_STRING` flag (`SORT_LOCALE_STRING` works similary, but depends on current locale, all values are treated as strings):

```
Array
(
    [0] => 1
    [1] => 1.5
    [2] => 2
    [3] => 2.72
    [4] => 3.14
    [5] => img1
    [6] => img10
    [7] => img2
)
```

Using `SORT_NATURAL` flag (note order of `img*` strings, it is *natural*):

```
Array
(
    [0] => 1
    [1] => 1.5
    [2] => 2
    [3] => 2.72
    [4] => 3.14
    [5] => img1
    [6] => img2
    [7] => img10
)
```

`SORT_FLAG_CASE` can be combined with `SORT_STRING` or `SORT_NATURAL` to do case-insensitive sort e.g.:

```
// works like SORT_NATURAL but is case-insensitive
sort($toSort, SORT_NATURAL | SORT_FLAG_CASE);
```

Comment: Wow thank you des i was looking at the link but it didnt tell me much, but now..., thank you i am reading.

Comment: Later I thought it wouldn't be enough, so I decided to answer. This is accually good question. I haven't tested those for uppercase strings, but this should be sufficient.

Comment: Why when i am trying use SORT_NATURAL the output is not the same is yours this is my code:http://pastebin.com/XtiDwg61 , and thank you.

Comment: The code is the same code for sure, but ideone is using PHP (php 5.2.11) and i am using wamp with (php 5.4.3) why do you think there is a difference between those two results?

Comment: I see, then it shouldn't work at all, because `SORT_NATURAL` was added in PHP 5.4. I've updated my answer with correct `SORT_NATURAL` results. Thanks for noticing!

Comment: The SORT_REGULAR is still not really clear to me. How do they consider one value smaller than another?

Comment: @donquixote [sort()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.sort.php) : "**SORT_REGULAR** - compare items normally (don't change types)"

Comment: @donquixote [sort()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.sort.php) : "**WARNING**

Be careful when sorting arrays with mixed types values because sort() can produce unpredictable results."

Comment: @donquixote take a look at [Why does SORT_REGULAR produce inconsistent results in PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20792028/why-does-sort-regular-produce-inconsistent-results-in-php)

Comment: @walkhard I saw the explanation from the manual, and I think it is stupid :) I mean "normally", what does this even mean? Maybe it means that two numbers are compared numerically, two strings are compared lexicographically, and string vs number we flip a coin? Or maybe it follows the behavior of the < and > operators?

Comment: https://3v4l.org/KCZo7 `assert('12' > '2' && '2' > '13 ' && '13 ' > '12');` circular, yeah! So if both of the two values look like numbers, numeric comparison happens. If less than both of them do, string comparison applies. How really bad :)

Comment: Ok apparently it is like this: If two strings both look like a number, or one of the two values _is_ a number, numeric comparison applies. Otherwise, string comparison applies.

Comment: Possibly, thought I guess it's unreliable.

Comment: This helped fix my Laravel 5.2 Collection sorting. Laravel documentation doesn't show this as an option (https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/collections#method-sortby), although the sortBy function in the Collection.php file does show it uses SORT_REGULAR as the default second parameter (which made sense in hindsight). I ended up going with: Item::where($itemQueryArray)->with($modelName)->get()->sortBy($sortText, SORT_STRING | SORT_FLAG_CASE);