# How does the sort_flag works for sorting the array?

Tags: php, arrays, sorting

I have an array to sort as

```
$numbers = array(24, 19, 3, 16, 56, 8, 171);
sort($numbers, SORT_STRING);
print_r($numbers);
```

And thus when i sort the array i get the result as

```
(
    [0] => 16
    [1] => 171
    [2] => 19
    [3] => 24
    [4] => 3
    [5] => 56
    [6] => 8
)
```

How does the `SORT_STRING` works can anybody explain it to me?

Comment: You might want `SORT_NATURAL`.

Comment: No i didn't understood the working of the flag at first but i do now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works as an ascending numeric values for the first digits(as 1 in 16) of all the numbers and after finishing them all,the pointer goes towards the digit next to it (as 6 in 16) and this is how it works so basically it arranges the digits from the left most digit and then goes on arranging them by the preceeding ones(right).

**For example:** comparing between 16 and 171

As both the numbers have their left-most digits as 1 it sorts it numbers based on their next digits(the right ones).

And thus by following the rule you get an result array as

```
(
    [0] => 16
    [1] => 171
    [2] => 19
    [3] => 24
    [4] => 3
    [5] => 56
    [6] => 8
)
```

Answer (score 2):

SORT_STRING will compare character by character as in a word. So letter A is "higher" (or lower, your choice) than B, B > C.

1 > 2, 2 > 3, 11 > 12 and so on.

So in your case, when comparing 24 with 19, it will compare 1 with 2 and then order.
As a second example, when comparing 19 with 16, first will compare 1 with 1, which is equal, then compare 9 with 6, making 6 (and 16) a higher order.

More info here: [PHP, sort, sort_flags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11168523/php-sort-sort-flags)

If you want to dig deeper, this is the link for the PHP source code.
This is the line where it choices the sort algorithm depending on the sort flag:
https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/50765075db6b6d5a9597589601c59f743f6ee9c8/ext/standard/array.c#L502

And here where it execute the comparison/sort:
https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/50765075db6b6d5a9597589601c59f743f6ee9c8/ext/standard/array.c#L207

And then it will call a zend operator:
https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/5430a466ff31422b436df076581d8345531db975/Zend/zend_operators.c

Answer (score 0):

The SORT_STRING compare items as strings. You can find more detail here: https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.sort.php
A simple example is when you sort your files or directories on you computer: the sorting is alphabetical order.